# C# Deleting wrong files

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to use a Linq query to grab files in a directory that meet my criteria. When I loop through the contents of my list and output to the console, it looks like it's grabbing the correct files (anything created more than 60 seconds ago), but when I try to loop through the contents of my list and DELETE those files, it's grabbing additional files instead of just those that are older than 60 seconds.

Code:

```
public static void purgeOldLogs()
{
    //Getting current Directory
    int LogPurgeTime = LogUtil.logPurgeTime;
    string directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(directory);

    //checking for older log files
    List<string> files = dir.GetFiles()
        .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("webMonlog") && x.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(LogPurgeTime))
        .Select(x => x.FullName)
        .ToList();

    Console.WriteLine("Getting old Log Files...");

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        FileInfo fileToDelete = new FileInfo(file);
        fileToDelete.Delete();
        Console.WriteLine(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"it's grabbing additional files"_ - no, it doesn't. There's nothing special about filenames in a string list. That `foreach()` loop is not going to make up files to delete that aren't in `files`. Do some more debugging and create a [mcve] including example input and output.

Comment: So what makes you think they are the wrong files, when you debug it, whats the date time on these files.

Comment: If `logPurgeTime` is a positive number you should use `DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-LogPurgeTime)`

Comment: I think the files are wrong because when I write the list to the console, the files look right, but when I delete the files in the list, a file that wasnt in the list when I wrote it to the console is being deleted.

Comment: @user9175041 if `logPurgeTime` is greater than zero you are selecting *all* files created before a *future* date.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos  - thanks, that worked for me.

Comment: @user9175041 change the type of `LogUtils.logPurgeTime` to `Timespan` so you won't get into similar trouble in the future.

Comment: @user9175041: since comments are not supposed to be answers you should thank those who answered your question ;-)

Comment: Just wanted to thank everyone who downvoted me! This is why i have to keep starting new accounts on here as a beginner programmer it really sucks. Thanks again for everyone who helped though.

Answer (score 2):

Unless `LogPurgeTime` is a negative value, `DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(LogPurgeTime)` refers to a time 60 seconds in the future. All files will have a creation time earlier than this.

Instead of just adding a `-` sign though and writing eg:

```
x.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-LogPurgeTime)
```

You could precalculate the time instance :

```
var latestTime=DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-LogPurgeTime);

....
.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("webMonlog") && x.CreationTime < latestTime)
```

Even better, change the type of `LogUtil.logPurgeTime` to [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). This way you won't have to make assumptions about what that integer value means, or check whether it's positive or negative.

```
var latestTime = DateTime.Now - LogUtil.logPurgeTime;
....
.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("webMonlog") && x.CreationTime < latestTime)
```

In the log configuration code you could parse a string to set the property, eg :

```
LogUtils.logPurgeTime = TimeSpan.Parse("00:01");
```

Finally, `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` returns `FileInfo` objects. There's no need to get the FullName just to recreate the FileInfo objects. There's no need to load all FileInfos in memory before filtering them. [EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383574(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an IEnumerable that starts returning results immediatelly. Finally, both GetFiles and EnumerateFiles accept a wildcard search pattern.

The code could be simplified to :

```
var latestTime = DateTime.Now - LogUtil.logPurgeTime;
var pattern = "webMonlog*";

var files = dir.EnumerateFiles(pattern)
               .Where(x => x.CreationTime < latestTime)
               .ToList();
Console.WriteLine("Getting old Log Files...");

foreach (var file in files)
{
    file.Delete();
    Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`CreationTime` is always lower than `DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(LogPurgeTime)`.

What you want is `DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Abs(LogPurgeTime)) > x.CreationTime`

Comment: Unless `LogPurgeTime` is negative. If it's positive, the expression should be `DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(- LogPurgeTime)`. It's equivalent to `DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(LogPurgeTime)`

Comment: That is true, but very counterintuitive.

Comment: `DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(- someValue)` is a *very* common expression. Putting the filed on the *write* though, essentially inverting how people think about expressions can be confusing.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added `Math.Abs`, so that it doesn't matter now what the sign is.

Comment: Do you still consider this more intuitive? It's now less visible what the condition is and what field is being compared. Fun fact - IBM's DB2 team wanted to enforce this syntax (value op field) in the early SQL days because it made it easier for them to parse. Even the IBMers in the SQL committee rebelled

Comment: I don't consider this variable name intuitive. `LogPurgeTime` suggests time, but it stores number of seconds. Why not `.AddMinutes()`?

Comment: I used the suggested approach of DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(- someValue) instead of the one suggested in this answer and it worked for me.

Comment: @FCin which brings us to "why an integer"? `logPurgeTime` should be a Timespan

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes it should. That's why this conversation is meaningless.